# AOT and JIT with build-optimizer

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular2-aot

I am following the solution [here](https://github.com/Alekcei/AotAndJit) of using the `JitCompilerFactory` to load the runtime compiler and custom decorators to preserve the component and module metadata. But with the angular-cli `--build-optimizer` flag I get:

> ERROR Error: Cannot resolve all parameters for 'Parser'(?). Make sure that all the parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type annotations and that 'Parser' is decorated with Injectable.

[Here](https://github.com/gatimus/compiler-test) is my minimal reproduction, run `ng serve --aot --build-optimizer`. As a control `ng serve --aot` works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use option `--build-optimizer` then `@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/webpack-loader` loader is added to webpack loaders list.

`@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/webpack-loader` removes `ctorParameters` definitions from types that is not part of `platformWhitelist` ([source](https://github.com/angular/devkit/blob/master/packages/angular_devkit/build_optimizer/src/transforms/scrub-file.ts#L23)):

```typescript
const platformWhitelist = [
  'PlatformRef_',
  'TestabilityRegistry',
  'Console',
  'BrowserPlatformLocation',
];
```

I think that's correct behavior.

To work around it you could initialize `ctorParameters` manually before `JitCompilerFactory` [is created](https://github.com/gatimus/compiler-test/blob/master/src/app/app.component.ts#L19):

```typescript
import { 
  Compiler, ɵConsole as Console,
  Optional, Inject, Injector, 
  PACKAGE_ROOT_URL 
} from '@angular/core';

import {
  JitCompilerFactory,
  TemplateParser, CompilerConfig, CompileReflector,
  ElementSchemaRegistry, I18NHtmlParser, TEMPLATE_TRANSFORMS, DirectiveNormalizer,
  ResourceLoader, UrlResolver, HtmlParser, CompileMetadataResolver, NgModuleResolver,
  DirectiveResolver, SummaryResolver, PipeResolver, StaticSymbolCache, 
  ERROR_COLLECTOR_TOKEN,
  StyleCompiler, ViewCompiler, NgModuleCompiler, JitCompiler
} from '@angular/compiler';

import * as compiler from '@angular/compiler';

export function compilerFactory() {
  restoreDecorators();

  return new JitCompilerFactory([{ useDebug: false, useJit: true }]).createCompiler();
}

function restoreDecorators() {
  (compiler.Parser as any).parameters = [compiler.Lexer];
  (TemplateParser as any).parameters = [
    CompilerConfig, CompileReflector, compiler.Parser, ElementSchemaRegistry,
    I18NHtmlParser, Console, [new Optional(), new Inject(TEMPLATE_TRANSFORMS)]
  ];
  (DirectiveNormalizer as any).parameters = [
    ResourceLoader, UrlResolver,
    HtmlParser, CompilerConfig
  ];
  (CompileMetadataResolver as any).parameters = [
    CompilerConfig, NgModuleResolver, DirectiveResolver, PipeResolver, SummaryResolver,
    ElementSchemaRegistry,
    DirectiveNormalizer, Console,
    [new Optional(), StaticSymbolCache],
    CompileReflector,
    [new Optional(), new Inject(ERROR_COLLECTOR_TOKEN)]
  ];
  (StyleCompiler as any).parameters = [UrlResolver];
  (ViewCompiler as any).parameters = [CompileReflector];
  (NgModuleCompiler as any).parameters = [CompileReflector];
  (NgModuleResolver as any).parameters = [CompileReflector];
  (DirectiveResolver as any).parameters = [CompileReflector];
  (PipeResolver as any).parameters = [CompileReflector];

  (JitCompiler as any).parameters = [
    Injector,
    CompileMetadataResolver,
    TemplateParser,
    StyleCompiler,
    ViewCompiler,
    NgModuleCompiler,
    SummaryResolver,
    CompilerConfig,
    Console
  ];
  (UrlResolver as any).parameters = [[new Inject(PACKAGE_ROOT_URL)]];
}
```

And it seems to be risky as **compiler is subject to internal changes**. It works for `@angular/compiler@4.4.5` but may not work for other releases.

Comment: I don't know what `ctorParameters` are but from context I'm gathering that it is how the DI knows what to inject to service's (and ect) constructors. Could it be as simple as adding `Compiler` to the `platformWhitelist` if you forked https://github.com/angular/devkit or made a feature request?

Comment: We shouldn't do it.